# "Unable to Download Metadata" when using Two Bindings

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, metadata, wcf-binding

In my book, it wants me to expose two endpoints using two bindings: WsHttpBinding & NetTCPBinding and host the service in a host application.

I use the following code in C# to try to connect to my service:

```
Uri BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:5640/SService.svc");

Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SServiceClient), BaseAddress);
ServiceMetadataBehavior Behaviour = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
Behaviour.HttpGetEnabled = true;
Behaviour.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
Host.Description.Behaviors.Add(Behaviour);
Host.Open();
```

On the service side I have:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService...

public class SService : IService....
```

Then in my Config file I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Behavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpBehaviour" name="SService.SService">

        <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="wsHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBindingConfig"
          contract="SService.IService" />

        <endpoint
          address=""
          binding="netTcpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NetTCPBindingConfig"
          contract="SService.IService" />

        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:5640/SService.svc" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:5641/SService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

      </service>
    </services>

  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

But when I try to add service reference to my host application, it says unable to download metadata from the address. I don't understand what is wrong and the teacher never taught this.. I decided to go ahead and look it up and learn ahead of time. I used the Editor to create the WebConfig shown above.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? I added Metadata behaviour through the editor and I set the HttpGetEnabled to true.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find a few issues with your code that can cause this issue:

`Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SServiceClient), BaseAddress)`. Pass here `typeof(SService.SService)` instead of `typeof(SServiceClient)`. Change like this:

```
Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SService.SService))
```

`<service behaviorConfiguration="WsHttpBehaviour"`. I guess this should be "Behavior" as you have defined that. Since you have metadata enabled in config, you may remove the lines of code which add a ServiceMetadataBehavior to your servicehost.

Here is a sample that you can use for reference:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="ConsoleApplication1.Service">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication1.IService" />
        <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="ConsoleApplication1.IService" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://<machinename>:5640/SService.svc" />
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://<machinename>:5641/SService.svc" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service));
            host.Open();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string DoWork();
    }

    public class Service : IService
    {
        public string DoWork()
        {
            return "Hello world";
        }
    }
}
```

Metadata will be automatically available at the http baseaddress defined in the config.

Comment: I get: "Could not find a base address that matches scheme net.tcp for the endpoint with binding NetTcpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]." When I do your changes.

Comment: I can see you have a net.tcp base address defined in the config. So no need to pass baseAddress in ServiceHost(). Did you try removing that?